# Interaction between a dropdown list and a card visual

Tags: powerbi

I have a table of number of visual:

visual_1000x123
0

1

I would like to use a dropdown list to let people select 0 or 1.
If 1 is selected, the calculate result will be xxx(let's say 55k).
If 0 is selected, the calculate will be 0.
Maybe I should mention that there is a time filter, which works well.

The result varies according to the selected period.

This measure keeps giving me 0:

```
measure = IF(MAX('Simulateur'[visual_1000x123])=0, 0,
CALCULATE(SUM('Prévision Leaderboard'[Budget_impressions/1000x123_et_1000x167])) +
CALCULATE(SUM('Prévision Middleboard'[Budget_impressions/1000x123_et_1000x167])))
```

This measure keeps return 55k:

```
measure = IF(MAX('Simulateur'[visual_1000x123])=1, 0,
CALCULATE(SUM('Prévision Leaderboard'[Budget_impressions/1000x123_et_1000x167]))+CALCULATE(SUM('Prévision Middleboard'[Budget_impressions/1000x123_et_1000x167])))
```

I also tried to multiply the number of visual, but it didn't return anything:

```
measure =
(CALCULATE(SUM('Prévision Leaderboard'[Budget_impressions/1000x123_et_1000x167])) +
CALCULATE(SUM('Prévision Middleboard'[Budget_impressions/1000x123_et_1000x167])))*MAX('Simulateur'[1000x123])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer myself.
It's due to my data structure. All the data was in one table and I should have them seperated into different tables.